# What am I doing wrong on the decimal button, seems my bool is off?

Tags: c#, winforms

I do not understand what I am doing incorrectly in my dotButton, it shows it but does not give correct results? Any advise?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private bool isFirst = true;
        private bool shouldClear = true;
        private double num1;
        private double num2;
        private double result = 0;
        private string symbol = string.Empty;
        private bool hasDecimal = false;

        private void numberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button sourceButton = (sender as Button);
            double oldNumber, buttonNumber, newNumber;

            if (shouldClear)
            {
                outputTextbox.Clear();
                oldNumber = 0;
                shouldClear = false;
            }
            else
            {
                oldNumber = double.Parse(outputTextbox.Text);
                hasDecimal = true;
            }

            buttonNumber = Double.Parse(sourceButton.Text);
            newNumber = (oldNumber * 10) + buttonNumber;

            if (isFirst)
            {
                num1 = newNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                num2 = newNumber;
            }
            outputTextbox.Text += sourceButton.Text;
            Calculate(symbol);
        }
        private void Calculate(string operatorSymbol)
        {
            if (isFirst)
            {
                result = num1;
                return;
            }
            switch (operatorSymbol)
            {
                case "+":
                    result = num1 + num2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result = num1 - num2;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result = num1 * num2;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void operatorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num1 = result;

            Button sourceButton = (sender as Button);
            string operatorSymbol = sourceButton.Text;

            if (isFirst)
                isFirst = false;

            hasDecimal = true;
            shouldClear = true;
            symbol = operatorSymbol;
            outputTextbox.Text = result.ToString();

        }

        private void equalsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputTextbox.Text = result.ToString();
            isFirst = true;
            shouldClear = true;
            hasDecimal = true;
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputTextbox.Text = "0";
            result = 0;
            isFirst = true;
            shouldClear = true;
            hasDecimal = false;
        }

        private void dotButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (hasDecimal)
                hasDecimal = true;
            isFirst = false;
            shouldClear = true;
            outputTextbox.Text = dotButton.Text;
            }
        }
    }


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.zeroButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.oneButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.twoButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.threeButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.fourButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.fiveButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.sixButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.sevenButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.eightButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.nineButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.dotButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.addButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.subtractButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.multiplyButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.divideButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.clearButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.equalsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.outputTextbox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // zeroButton
            // 
            this.zeroButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 230);
            this.zeroButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.zeroButton.Name = "zeroButton";
            this.zeroButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 41);
            this.zeroButton.TabIndex = 0;
            this.zeroButton.Text = "0";
            this.zeroButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.zeroButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // oneButton
            // 
            this.oneButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 184);
            this.oneButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.oneButton.Name = "oneButton";
            this.oneButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.oneButton.TabIndex = 1;
            this.oneButton.Text = "1";
            this.oneButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.oneButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // twoButton
            // 
            this.twoButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(51, 184);
            this.twoButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.twoButton.Name = "twoButton";
            this.twoButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.twoButton.TabIndex = 2;
            this.twoButton.Text = "2";
            this.twoButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.twoButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // threeButton
            // 
            this.threeButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 184);
            this.threeButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.threeButton.Name = "threeButton";
            this.threeButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.threeButton.TabIndex = 3;
            this.threeButton.Text = "3";
            this.threeButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.threeButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // fourButton
            // 
            this.fourButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 139);
            this.fourButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.fourButton.Name = "fourButton";
            this.fourButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.fourButton.TabIndex = 4;
            this.fourButton.Text = "4";
            this.fourButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.fourButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // fiveButton
            // 
            this.fiveButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(51, 139);
            this.fiveButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.fiveButton.Name = "fiveButton";
            this.fiveButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.fiveButton.TabIndex = 5;
            this.fiveButton.Text = "5";
            this.fiveButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.fiveButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // sixButton
            // 
            this.sixButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 139);
            this.sixButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.sixButton.Name = "sixButton";
            this.sixButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.sixButton.TabIndex = 6;
            this.sixButton.Text = "6";
            this.sixButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.sixButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // sevenButton
            // 
            this.sevenButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 93);
            this.sevenButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.sevenButton.Name = "sevenButton";
            this.sevenButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.sevenButton.TabIndex = 7;
            this.sevenButton.Text = "7";
            this.sevenButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.sevenButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // eightButton
            // 
            this.eightButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(51, 93);
            this.eightButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.eightButton.Name = "eightButton";
            this.eightButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.eightButton.TabIndex = 8;
            this.eightButton.Text = "8";
            this.eightButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.eightButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // nineButton
            // 
            this.nineButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 93);
            this.nineButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.nineButton.Name = "nineButton";
            this.nineButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.nineButton.TabIndex = 9;
            this.nineButton.Text = "9";
            this.nineButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.nineButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.numberButton_Click);
            // 
            // dotButton
            // 
            this.dotButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 230);
            this.dotButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.dotButton.Name = "dotButton";
            this.dotButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 41);
            this.dotButton.TabIndex = 10;
            this.dotButton.Text = ".";
            this.dotButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.dotButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dotButton_Click);
            // 
            // addButton
            // 
            this.addButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(135, 230);
            this.addButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.addButton.Name = "addButton";
            this.addButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.addButton.TabIndex = 11;
            this.addButton.Text = "+";
            this.addButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.addButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.operatorButton_Click);
            // 
            // subtractButton
            // 
            this.subtractButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(135, 184);
            this.subtractButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.subtractButton.Name = "subtractButton";
            this.subtractButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.subtractButton.TabIndex = 12;
            this.subtractButton.Text = "-";
            this.subtractButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.subtractButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.operatorButton_Click);
            // 
            // multiplyButton
            // 
            this.multiplyButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(135, 139);
            this.multiplyButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.multiplyButton.Name = "multiplyButton";
            this.multiplyButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.multiplyButton.TabIndex = 13;
            this.multiplyButton.Text = "*";
            this.multiplyButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.multiplyButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.operatorButton_Click);
            // 
            // divideButton
            // 
            this.divideButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(135, 93);
            this.divideButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.divideButton.Name = "divideButton";
            this.divideButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 41);
            this.divideButton.TabIndex = 14;
            this.divideButton.Text = "/";
            this.divideButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.divideButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.operatorButton_Click);
            // 
            // clearButton
            // 
            this.clearButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 48);
            this.clearButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.clearButton.Name = "clearButton";
            this.clearButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 41);
            this.clearButton.TabIndex = 15;
            this.clearButton.Text = "Clear";
            this.clearButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.clearButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.clearButton_Click);
            // 
            // equalsButton
            // 
            this.equalsButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 48);
            this.equalsButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.equalsButton.Name = "equalsButton";
            this.equalsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 41);
            this.equalsButton.TabIndex = 16;
            this.equalsButton.Text = "=";
            this.equalsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.equalsButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.equalsButton_Click);
            // 
            // outputTextbox
            // 
            this.outputTextbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 3);
            this.outputTextbox.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.outputTextbox.Multiline = true;
            this.outputTextbox.Name = "outputTextbox";
            this.outputTextbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(164, 41);
            this.outputTextbox.TabIndex = 17;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 280);
            this.Controls.Add(this.outputTextbox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.equalsButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.clearButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.divideButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.multiplyButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.subtractButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.addButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dotButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.nineButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.eightButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.sevenButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.sixButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.fiveButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.fourButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.threeButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.twoButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.oneButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.zeroButton);
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button zeroButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button oneButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button twoButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button threeButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button fourButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button fiveButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button sixButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button sevenButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button eightButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button nineButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button dotButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button addButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button subtractButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button multiplyButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button divideButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button clearButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button equalsButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox outputTextbox;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the designer.cs too please?

Comment: Shouldn't this: `if (hasDecimal) hasDecimal = true;` just be: `hasDecimal = true;`?  Seems like hitting dot should mean it's got a decimal.

Comment: @ebyrob yes, I made a modification, I think it may be with a parse. as it s not recognizing the dot as being integrated into a number

Comment: Try combining with @Raphael's `+=` change.  Seems like both would be necessary, and maybe something more.

Comment: Can you think of a more worthless statement than, *"does not give correct results?"*   What results did you expect? What results did you actually get?

Comment: @abelenky I hit 3.3 and when I press the + button it gives me 6

Comment: There is a solution to this.  It involves: `hasDecimal = result == Math.Round(result, 0);` and in number click: `if (hasDecimal) { newNumber = oldNumber + (buttonNumber / Math.Pow(10, outputTextbox.Text.Length - outputTextbox.Text.IndexOf('.'))); }`.  Also, you'll want to remove most times `hasDecimal = true`.

Comment: I had to scrap my entire code. I never got it to work with this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that you want

```
outputTextbox.Text += dotButton.Text;
```

(you missed the `+`)

Comment: As the other answer and its comments disappeared, I re-add the Uwe Keim's one : `if (hasDecimal) hasDecimal = true` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yea that should not be there

Comment: Does this answer resolve your issue? Please mark it as correct if it does.

Comment: No it does not. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: The += does not work either

Comment: @Azzamean can you add the Form1.Designer.cs code to your question please?

Comment: @MrGray I added the designer.cs

Answer (score 1):

In your method for `dotButton_Click` you have a `boolean` `shouldClear` set to `true`:

```
private void dotButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hasDecimal)
        hasDecimal = true;
    isFirst = false;
    shouldClear = true;
    outputTextbox.Text += dotButton.Text;
}
```

Change it to `false`.

And: `outputTextbox.Text += dotButton.Text;` with a `+=` not just an `=`.

The following lines have a problem:

```
        buttonNumber = Double.Parse(sourceButton.Text);
        newNumber = (oldNumber*10) + buttonNumber;
```

Why are you multiplying by 10?

There seems to be quite a lot of logic a bit mixed up here, I have solved the first issue you need to debug your code and step through it. You will see the sequence of events are not in the order you want them to be. Too many things here to change, and it will take a rewrite that I am sure you would want to do yourself rather than have me do for you... Even if I had the time.

Comment: That allows me to put 3.3 and when I hit, per say, the + operator 6 appears in the box. It is not recognizing 3.3 as a number is seems